# Prevent binding execution in getter/setter

Tags: events, ember.js

In my Ember Controller I am using lazy loading to fetch additional data whenever the configuration is changed. Therefore I want to delay the execution of the binding until all depending data is loaded. I thought returning a false value as the setters result will prevent the binding execution but the binding is still executed. How can I delay the binding execution till loading has finished?

```
App.ConfigController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   currentConfiguration: null,

   configuration: function(key, value){
     if(arguments.length === 1){
         return this.get('currentConfiguration');
     }
     var self = this;
     // load additional data 
        this.loadData(id, function(data){
                            self.set('currentConfiguration', value);
                            return value;
                           })
     }
     return false;
   }.property('currentConfiguration'),

    loadData: function(id, resultHandler, faultHandler){
       var self = this;
       var uri = 'http://foo.com/+id;

       $.getJSON(uri)
        .success(function(data, status, jqXHR){
            resultHandler(data);
        })
        .error(faultHandler);
    },

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to prevent binding execution as you wish. The way I would approach this is to have two separate properties; set one, and observe it to update the second, and bind to the second. Something like this:

```
App.ConfigController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  configuration: null, // <- set this property
  configurationDidChange: function(){
    var self = this;
    // load additional data 
    this.loadData(id, function(data){
                        self.set('configurationData', value);
                       });
  }.observes('configuration'),
  configurationData: null <- bind to this property

  loadData: function(id, resultHandler, faultHandler){
    // ... as you have it 
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Wouldn't it be useful to have some kind of logic to prevent binding execution? Since Bindings are represented as objects they could be treated as plain JS - events which offer a prevendDefault method.

Comment: @Franatique you're thinking of properties as events, but they are designed to be thought of more as properties that can be bound to one another. To turn a property change into an event, observers are used. The design is internally consistent, and my opinion is that the introduction of something that would somehow prevent binding execution within the definition of a property setter would add unnecessary complexity.